# PSSession timeouts, broken vs disconnected?

Tags: powershell

I have a long running process that keeps coming back with a state of broken, and it's definitely not running everything in the invoke-command scriptblock, but I can't seem to figure out why.

Here's the code I use to create the session (note the timeout).

```
$sessionOption = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck -IdleTimeout 3600000 # 60 minutes
$session = New-PSSession -UseSSL -SessionOption $sessionOption -ComputerName $hostname -Credential $Credential
```

I've read a truckload on what it means to have a disconnected connection, but I don't believe that's what is hapening here.

Can I get guidance as to how I should move forward to identify the issue?

And does anyone have a good book they can recommend for an in-depth understanding of Powershell?  It's getting old running into these sorts of issues and not having a clue what's going on (PS seems unnecessarily complicated in a lot of ways).

Comment: does the code you are running work if you run it locally on the machine? maybe its just your code failing that causes the exit? regarding books i can recommend "Powershell best practices" by ed wilson

Comment: the code is just calling Start-Process <pathToAVG> -Wait, and AVG is installing.  Sometimes AVG doesn't install completely, but I suspect that's due to the timeout causing the session on the other end to be tore down (even though documentation says it won't if it's disconnected).  When I take another look at it I'm going to remove the -Wait flag and just busy loop looking for the AVG Shield Service to come up.  I suspect the issue may be because I don't know what PS/WinRM considers to be "idle".  I'm wondering if looping will be considered active instead of waiting on Start-Process

Comment: That's why I asked for an in-depth recommendation for PS, I'm making a lot of guesses as to what the issue could be and I wish I understood the internals better.